# Getting all translations in a specific namespace from angular-translate

Tags: angular-translate

In order to populate a service with data, I would like to get all translations beneath a specific namespace from angular-translate's *$translate* service.

Basically what I am looking for is something like this (which is not supported):

```
$translate('SOME.NAMESPACE.*').then(...);
```

Since this does not exist, I guess my best approach at this time is to parse the fallback translation table I provide synchronously with my app myself?

Comment: I think its not possible, you should retrieve it seperatey by specifying, like this  : 

$translate('NAMESPACE.SUB');

Comment: hmm, really would like to see these functionality

Comment: Right now (may 8th, 2017) this is supported according to the official docs here (angular-translate.github.io/docs) but i'm no table to get this working properly. Did you find any solution in the end, @Claus Conrad?!